# Objective-c check if data model changed values state

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

Is there any patters that I can use to understand if my data model has changed to original state.

Let's see at situation when I have an object Order which can include some price info, items number, order notes info and etc. So at start it's an empty order and if I will update any properties by adding something new I will need to detect that the model exactly changed.

So let's say I put 5 items number at start and save data mode of Order. Then I want to update this model by putting 2 new items then KVO or any other tool should tell me about updates in data model, but if I set 5 items number one more time (like `NSInteger itemNumbers = 5`) so it means I triggered setter of the property, but I have not modified original value.

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to know how to send KVO notifications or how to receive them? Or do you want to know how to not send KVO notifications when a property changes to the same value?

Comment: @Willeke I mean maybe there is some pattern or technic that I can apply. For sure I can use swizilling or KVO, but if someone have references/patterns or technics I will be glad to hear.